# SQL Compare two tables update and set flag

Tags: sql

I have two tables, the first one is called table1, the structure and contents are shown below

```
+--+-----+------+------+
|ID|fname|Lname |Status|
+--+-----+------+------+
|1 |Pat  |Test  |      |
+--+-----+------+------+
|2 |Su   |Test2 |      |
+--+-----+------+------+
|3 |Bri  |Test4 |      |
+--+-----+------+------+
|4 |Mel  |Gi    |      |
+--+-----+------+------+
|5 |Good |Record|      |
+--+-----+------+------+
|6 |Tr   |BL    |      |
+--+-----+------+------+
```

The second table has updates that need to be committed to table1.

```
+--+-------+-----+
|ID|Fname  |Lname|
+--+-------+-----+
|1 |Patrick|Cool |
+--+-------+-----+
|2 |Susun  |Smart|
+--+-------+-----+
|6 |True   |Blood|
+--+-------+-----+
```

I would like to compare both tables and update table1 with the contents of table 2. (compare using ID) If any update is done on any row, i would like the status column to be marked as UPDATED. If a row exists in table1 but it doesnt exist in table2 i would like the status of that row in table1 marked as DELETE. Rows with no changes should have no status

The after the update the final output should resemble

```
+--+-------+------+------+
|ID|fname  |Lname |Status|
+--+-------+------+------+
|1 |Patrick|Cool  |UPDATE|
+--+-------+------+------+
|2 |Susun  |Smart |UPDATE|
+--+-------+------+------+
|3 |Brian  |Brown |DELETE|
+--+-------+------+------+
|4 |Mel    |Gibson|DELETE|
+--+-------+------+------+
|5 |Good   |Record||
+--+-------+------+------+
|6 |True   |Blood |UPDATE|
+--+-------+------+------+
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried writing this yourself?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `Rows with no changes should have no status`? How do you determine if there is any change? By comparing all the column values?

Comment: And make sure to add which database tool you're using.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and up has a [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement. That is why @Mike M asked about the RDBMS.

Comment: @astander: to be precise: the database *tool* is not relevant here, the DBMS being used is.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a nested query?
for the deleted updated

```
UPDATE table_1 SET status = "DELETED" WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM table_2
)
```

for update

```
UPDATE table_1, table_2 
SET table_1.status = "UPDATED", 
    table_1.fName = table_2.FName, 
    table_1.lName = table_2.LName 
WHERE table_1.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM table_1, table_2 
    WHERE table_1.id = table_2.id AND 
          (table_1.fName!= table_2.FName OR table_1.lName!=table_2.LName)
)
```

(edited)update with join

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET table_1.fName = t2.FName, table_1.lName = t2.LName, table_1.status = "UPDATED" 
FROM table_1 AS t1 JOIN table_2 AS t2 USING (id) 
WHERE t1.fName!=t2.FName OR t1.lName!=t2.LName
```

Comment: a join could also do for the subquery in the update.

Answer (score 0):

hashbrown ->

the code above is just not showing the "DELETED" , "UPDATED" , sorry about that (:
So I'll add this code which can help

Read more in [Simple-talk-> the merge statement in sql server 2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/)

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('BookInventory', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.BookInventory;

 CREATE TABLE dbo.BookInventory  -- target
 (
 TitleID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Title NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 Quantity INT NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT Quantity_Default_1 DEFAULT 0
 );
 IF OBJECT_ID ('BookOrder', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.BookOrder;

 CREATE TABLE dbo.BookOrder  -- source
 (
  TitleID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Title NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Quantity INT NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT Quantity_Default_2 DEFAULT 0
 );
  INSERT BookInventory VALUES
   (1, 'The Catcher in the Rye', 6),
   (2, 'Pride and Prejudice', 3),
   (3, 'The Great Gatsby', 0),
   (5, 'Jane Eyre', 0),
   (6, 'Catch 22', 0),
   (8, 'Slaughterhouse Five', 4);
  INSERT BookOrder VALUES
   (1, 'The Catcher in the Rye', 3),
   (3, 'The Great Gatsby', 0),
   (4, 'Gone with the Wind', 4),
   (5, 'Jane Eyre', 5),
   (7, 'Age of Innocence', 8);

 --1 Implementing the WHEN MATCHED Clause
  MERGE BookInventory bi
  USING BookOrder bo
   ON bi.TitleID = bo.TitleID
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
   SET bi.Quantity = bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity;

 SELECT * FROM BookInventory;

 --2 Implementing the WHEN MATCHED Clause (Delete)
  MERGE BookInventory bi
  USING BookOrder bo
  ON bi.TitleID = bo.TitleID
  WHEN MATCHED AND
   bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity = 0 THEN
  DELETE
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
   SET bi.Quantity = bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity;

 SELECT * FROM BookInventory;

  --3 Implementing the WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET] Clause
  MERGE BookInventory bi
  USING BookOrder bo
  ON bi.TitleID = bo.TitleID
  WHEN MATCHED AND
  bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity = 0 THEN
  DELETE
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET bi.Quantity = bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (TitleID, Title, Quantity)
  VALUES (bo.TitleID, bo.Title,bo.Quantity);

  SELECT * FROM BookInventory;

  --4 Implementing the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE Clause
  MERGE BookInventory bi
  USING BookOrder bo
  ON bi.TitleID = bo.TitleID
  WHEN MATCHED AND
   bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity = 0 THEN
  DELETE
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET bi.Quantity = bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (TitleID, Title, Quantity)
  VALUES (bo.TitleID, bo.Title,bo.Quantity)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  AND bi.Quantity = 0 THEN
  DELETE;

  SELECT * FROM BookInventory;

  --5 Implementing the OUTPUT Clause
    DECLARE @MergeOutput TABLE
    (
   ActionType NVARCHAR(10),
   DelTitleID INT,
   InsTitleID INT,
   DelTitle NVARCHAR(50),
   InsTitle NVARCHAR(50),
   DelQuantity INT,
   InsQuantity INT
   );

 MERGE BookInventory bi
 USING BookOrder bo
 ON bi.TitleID = bo.TitleID
 WHEN MATCHED AND
 bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity = 0 THEN
 DELETE
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE
 SET bi.Quantity = bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (TitleID, Title, Quantity)
   VALUES (bo.TitleID, bo.Title,bo.Quantity)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
 AND bi.Quantity = 0 THEN
 DELETE
OUTPUT
  $action,
  DELETED.TitleID,
  INSERTED.TitleID,
  DELETED.Title,
  INSERTED.Title,
  DELETED.Quantity,
  INSERTED.Quantity
  INTO @MergeOutput;

 SELECT * FROM BookInventory;

 SELECT * FROM @MergeOutput
 --where ActionType = 'UPDATE'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Merge Clause and OUTPUT

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.Purchases', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Purchases;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Purchases (
ProductID int, CustomerID int, PurchaseDate datetime, 
CONSTRAINT PK_PurchProdID PRIMARY KEY(ProductID,CustomerID));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Purchases VALUES(707, 11794, '20060821'),
(707, 15160, '20060825'),(708, 18529, '20060821'),
(711, 11794, '20060821'),(711, 19585, '20060822'),
(712, 14680, '20060825'),(712, 21524, '20060825'),
(712, 19072, '20060821'),(870, 15160, '20060823'),
(870, 11927, '20060824'),(870, 18749, '20060825');
GO
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.FactBuyingHabits', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE dbo.FactBuyingHabits;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.FactBuyingHabits (
 ProductID int, CustomerID int, LastPurchaseDate datetime, 
 CONSTRAINT PK_FactProdID PRIMARY KEY(ProductID,CustomerID));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.FactBuyingHabits VALUES(707, 11794, '20060814'),
(707, 18178, '20060818'),(864, 14114, '20060818'),
(866, 13350, '20060818'),(866, 20201, '20060815'),
(867, 20201, '20060814'),(869, 19893, '20060815'),
(870, 17151, '20060818'),(870, 15160, '20060817'),
(871, 21717, '20060817'),(871, 21163, '20060815'),
(871, 13350, '20060815'),(873, 23381, '20060815');
GO

select * from Purchases;
select * from FactBuyingHabits;

--Now this is the Place where you do the manipulation you want
MERGE dbo.FactBuyingHabits AS Target
USING (SELECT CustomerID, ProductID, PurchaseDate FROM dbo.Purchases) AS Source
ON (Target.ProductID = Source.ProductID AND Target.CustomerID = Source.CustomerID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Target.LastPurchaseDate = Source.PurchaseDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (CustomerID, ProductID, LastPurchaseDate)
   VALUES (Source.CustomerID, Source.ProductID, Source.PurchaseDate)
   OUTPUT $action, Inserted.ProductId InsertedProductId, 
            Inserted.CustomerId InsertedCustomerId,
            Inserted.LastPurchaseDate InsertedLastPurchaseDate, 
            Deleted.ProductId DeletedProductId, 
            Deleted.CustomerId DeletedCustomerId, 
            Deleted.LastPurchaseDate DeletedLastPurchaseDate; 


   select * from FactBuyingHabits;


   drop table FactBuyingHabits;
   drop table Purchases;
```